# openshift v3 pod file not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I am testing Openshift Origin v3. I installed it as a docker container following the instructions. I also deployed all the streams in roles/openshift_examples/files/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json.

I am now testing the installation by deploying a dummy php application from Github. I am able to create the project and application. However the builds are stuck in status "pending". In the events tab, I see plenty of messages like this one:

```
"Unable to mount volumes for pod "hello-world-1-build_php1": 
IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/9377d3b4-9887-
11e5-81fe-00215abe5482/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-dockercfg-x2ijq-
push"): file does not exist (5 times in the last 40 seconds)"
```

I tried also with a java application and the tomcat docker image, but got the same error messages. Looks like a Kubernetes configuration issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

UPDATE1: 
logs from the origin container show a bit more information about the error:

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "deployment-example-2-deploy_test1": IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/70f69f8c-98d3-11e5-8d98-00215abe5482/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/deployer-token-8cfv8"): file does not exist; skipping pod
E1202 09:12:24.269145    4396 pod_workers.go:113] Error syncing pod 70f69f8c-98d3-11e5-8d98-00215abe5482, skipping: IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/70f69f8c-98d3-11e5-8d98-00215abe5482/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/deployer-token-8cfv8"): file does not exist
W1202 09:12:34.229374    4396 kubelet.go:1690] Orphaned volume "ac11a2b5-9880-11e5-81fe-00215abe5482/builder-dockercfg-va0cl-push" found, tearing down volume
E1202 09:12:34.287847    4396 kubelet.go:1696] Could not tear down volume "ac11a2b5-9880-11e5-81fe-00215abe5482/builder-dockercfg-va0cl-push": IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/ac11a2b5-9880-11e5-81fe-00215abe5482/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-dockercfg-va0cl-push"): file does not exist
```

The log entries of the start of the origin container:

```
202 09:12:13.992293    4396 start_master.go:278] assetConfig.loggingPublicURL: invalid value '', Details: required to view aggregated container logs in the console
W1202 09:12:13.992442    4396 start_master.go:278] assetConfig.metricsPublicURL: invalid value '', Details: required to view cluster metrics in the console
I1202 09:12:14.784026    4396 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.
I1202 09:12:14.981775    4396 start_master.go:388] Starting master on 0.0.0.0:8443 (v1.1-270-ge592c18)
I1202 09:12:14.981825    4396 start_master.go:389] Public master address is https://192.168.178.55:8443
I1202 09:12:14.981855    4396 start_master.go:393] Using images from "openshift/origin-<component>:v1.1"
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574421 I | etcdserver: name = openshift.local
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574455 I | etcdserver: data dir = openshift.local.etcd
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574465 I | etcdserver: member dir = openshift.local.etcd/member
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574472 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574480 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574489 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 0
2015-12-02 09:12:15.574505 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = https://192.168.178.55:4001
2015-12-02 09:12:15.606296 I | etcdserver: restarting member 2041635cb479cd3a in cluster 6a5d0422e654089a at commit index 3846
2015-12-02 09:12:15.609623 I | raft: 2041635cb479cd3a became follower at term 2
2015-12-02 09:12:15.609663 I | raft: newRaft 2041635cb479cd3a [peers: [], term: 2, commit: 3846, applied: 0, lastindex: 3846, lastterm: 2]
2015-12-02 09:12:15.609815 I | etcdserver: set snapshot count to default 10000
2015-12-02 09:12:15.609829 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 2.1.2, cluster version: to_be_decided]
I1202 09:12:15.611196    4396 etcd.go:68] Started etcd at 192.168.178.55:4001
2015-12-02 09:12:15.624029 N | etcdserver: added local member 2041635cb479cd3a [https://192.168.178.55:7001] to cluster 6a5d0422e654089a
2015-12-02 09:12:15.624349 N | etcdserver: set the initial cluster version to 2.1.0
I1202 09:12:15.645761    4396 run_components.go:181] Using default project node label selector: 
2015-12-02 09:12:17.009875 I | raft: 2041635cb479cd3a is starting a new election at term 2
2015-12-02 09:12:17.009915 I | raft: 2041635cb479cd3a became candidate at term 3
2015-12-02 09:12:17.009970 I | raft: 2041635cb479cd3a received vote from 2041635cb479cd3a at term 3
2015-12-02 09:12:17.009995 I | raft: 2041635cb479cd3a became leader at term 3
2015-12-02 09:12:17.010011 I | raft: raft.node: 2041635cb479cd3a elected leader 2041635cb479cd3a at term 3
2015-12-02 09:12:17.059445 I | etcdserver: published {Name:openshift.local ClientURLs:[https://192.168.178.55:4001]} to cluster 6a5d0422e654089a
W1202 09:12:17.111262    4396 controller.go:290] Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to &{{ } {kubernetes  default  c10e12cf-98d0-11e5-8d98-00215abe5482 8 0 2015-12-02 08:43:26 +0000 UTC <nil> <nil> map[] map[]} [{[{192.168.178.55 <nil>}] [] [{https 8443 TCP} {dns 53 UDP} {dns-tcp 53 TCP}]}]}
I1202 09:12:17.524735    4396 master.go:232] Started Kubernetes API at 0.0.0.0:8443/api/v1
I1202 09:12:17.524914    4396 master.go:232] Started Kubernetes API Extensions at 0.0.0.0:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1
I1202 09:12:17.525038    4396 master.go:232] Started Origin API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oapi/v1
I1202 09:12:17.525049    4396 master.go:232] Started OAuth2 API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oauth
I1202 09:12:17.525055    4396 master.go:232] Started Login endpoint at 0.0.0.0:8443/login
I1202 09:12:17.525061    4396 master.go:232] Started Web Console 0.0.0.0:8443/console/
I1202 09:12:17.525067    4396 master.go:232] Started Swagger Schema API at 0.0.0.0:8443/swaggerapi/
2015-12-02 09:12:18.523290 I | http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.178.21:50932: EOF
2015-12-02 09:12:18.537124 I | http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.178.21:50933: EOF
2015-12-02 09:12:18.549780 I | http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.178.21:50934: EOF
2015-12-02 09:12:18.556966 I | http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.178.21:50935: EOF
2015-12-02 09:12:20.117727 I | skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp4://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
2015-12-02 09:12:20.117804 I | skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp4://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
I1202 09:12:20.217891    4396 run_components.go:176] DNS listening at 0.0.0.0:53
I1202 09:12:20.225439    4396 start_master.go:519] Controllers starting (*)
E1202 09:12:20.702335    4396 serviceaccounts_controller.go:218] serviceaccounts "default" already exists
I1202 09:12:21.505391    4396 nodecontroller.go:133] Sending events to api server.
I1202 09:12:21.507690    4396 start_master.go:563] Started Kubernetes Controllers
W1202 09:12:21.944254    4396 nodecontroller.go:572] Missing timestamp for Node intweb3. Assuming now as a timestamp.
I1202 09:12:21.944570    4396 event.go:216] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"intweb3", UID:"intweb3", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): reason: 'RegisteredNode' Node intweb3 event: Registered Node intweb3 in NodeController
I1202 09:12:22.662116    4396 start_node.go:179] Starting a node connected to https://192.168.178.55:8443
I1202 09:12:22.670163    4396 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.
I1202 09:12:22.670239    4396 start_node.go:284] Starting node intweb3 (v1.1-270-ge592c18)
W1202 09:12:22.681308    4396 node.go:121] Error running 'chcon' to set the kubelet volume root directory SELinux context: exit status 1
I1202 09:12:22.698136    4396 node.go:56] Connecting to Docker at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I1202 09:12:22.717904    4396 manager.go:128] cAdvisor running in container: "/docker/f80b92397b6eb9052cf318d7225d21eb66941fcb333f16fe2b0330af629f73dd"
I1202 09:12:22.932096    4396 fs.go:108] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/sda1:{mountpoint:/rootfs/boot major:8 minor:1 fsType: blockSize:0} /dev/mapper/intweb3--vg-root:{mountpoint:/rootfs major:252 minor:0 fsType: blockSize:0}]
I1202 09:12:22.949204    4396 node.go:251] Started Kubernetes Proxy on 0.0.0.0
I1202 09:12:22.974678    4396 start_master.go:582] Started Origin Controllers
I1202 09:12:22.999204    4396 machine.go:48] Couldn't collect info from any of the files in "/etc/machine-id,/var/lib/dbus/machine-id"
I1202 09:12:22.999311    4396 manager.go:163] Machine: {NumCores:2 CpuFrequency:2667000 MemoryCapacity:1010421760 MachineID: SystemUUID:26A5835E-1781-DD11-BBDA-5ABE54820021 BootID:6cbd9dcc-5d4d-414d-96e7-c8a41de013f7 Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/mapper/intweb3--vg-root Capacity:156112113664} {Device:/dev/sda1 Capacity:246755328}] DiskMap:map[252:0:{Name:dm-0 Major:252 Minor:0 Size:158737629184 Scheduler:none} 252:1:{Name:dm-1 Major:252 Minor:1 Size:1044381696 Scheduler:none} 8:0:{Name:sda Major:8 Minor:0 Size:160041885696 Scheduler:deadline}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:eth0 MacAddress:00:21:5a:be:54:82 Speed:1000 Mtu:1500}] Topology:[{Id:0 Memory:1010421760 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]}] Caches:[]}] CloudProvider:Unknown InstanceType:Unknown}
I1202 09:12:23.010686    4396 manager.go:169] Version: {KernelVersion:3.19.0-25-generic ContainerOsVersion:CentOS Linux 7 (Core) DockerVersion:1.9.1 CadvisorVersion: CadvisorRevision:}
I1202 09:12:23.011734    4396 server.go:820] Watching apiserver
I1202 09:12:23.253556    4396 manager.go:191] Setting dockerRoot to /var/lib/docker
I1202 09:12:23.270558    4396 plugins.go:56] Registering credential provider: .dockercfg
I1202 09:12:23.363525    4396 server.go:779] Started kubelet
E1202 09:12:23.363724    4396 kubelet.go:812] Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /
I1202 09:12:23.370771    4396 kubelet.go:833] Running in container "/kubelet"
I1202 09:12:23.370860    4396 server.go:104] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
I1202 09:12:23.734095    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "decodeNodeList *[]api.ImageStream" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.154869743 +0000 UTC):
[579.19167ms] [579.19167ms] Decoded 1 nodes
[579.193136ms] [1.466µs] END
I1202 09:12:23.734149    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "decodeNodeList *[]api.ImageStream" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.154865413 +0000 UTC):
[3.352µs] [3.352µs] Decoding dir /openshift.io/imagestreams/test1 START
[579.252571ms] [579.249219ms] Decoding dir /openshift.io/imagestreams/test1 END
[579.255504ms] [2.933µs] Decoded 1 nodes
[579.257181ms] [1.677µs] END
I1202 09:12:23.734204    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "List *api.ImageStreamList" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.001854335 +0000 UTC):
[1.676µs] [1.676µs] About to list directory
[732.327694ms] [732.326018ms] List extracted
[732.330138ms] [2.444µs] END
I1202 09:12:23.773150    4396 factory.go:236] Registering Docker factory
I1202 09:12:23.779446    4396 factory.go:93] Registering Raw factory
I1202 09:12:24.069082    4396 manager.go:1006] Started watching for new ooms in manager
I1202 09:12:24.074624    4396 oomparser.go:183] oomparser using systemd
I1202 09:12:24.111389    4396 kubelet.go:944] Node intweb3 was previously registered
I1202 09:12:24.112362    4396 manager.go:250] Starting recovery of all containers
I1202 09:12:24.166309    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "decodeNodeList *[]api.ImageStream" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.155013407 +0000 UTC):
[1.011259672s] [1.011259672s] Decoded 1 nodes
[1.011261767s] [2.095µs] END
I1202 09:12:24.166422    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "decodeNodeList *[]api.ImageStream" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.155011032 +0000 UTC):
[1.327µs] [1.327µs] Decoding dir /openshift.io/imagestreams/test1 START
[1.01138385s] [1.011382523s] Decoding dir /openshift.io/imagestreams/test1 END
[1.011386853s] [3.003µs] Decoded 1 nodes
[1.01138839s] [1.537µs] END
I1202 09:12:24.166561    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "List *api.ImageStreamList" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.002949866 +0000 UTC):
[3.142µs] [3.142µs] About to list etcd node
[152.060049ms] [152.056907ms] Etcd node listed
[1.163577016s] [1.011516967s] Node list decoded
[1.163587911s] [10.895µs] END
I1202 09:12:24.166656    4396 trace.go:57] Trace "List *api.ImageStreamList" (started 2015-12-02 09:12:23.002947281 +0000 UTC):
[1.188µs] [1.188µs] About to list directory
[1.16368555s] [1.163684362s] List extracted
[1.163687576s] [2.026µs] END
I1202 09:12:24.196265    4396 manager.go:255] Recovery completed
I1202 09:12:24.215711    4396 manager.go:118] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
I1202 09:12:24.215792    4396 kubelet.go:2056] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
```

UPDATE2

```
$sudo docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

@Clayton: Can you share any link about the mount bug that is supposed to be fixed in 1.10? Thanks!

Comment: What are the build logs or logs on your container telling? Sometimes they show more than the errors in the eventstab of the console.

Comment: I am having the same problem when running origin in docker container. Have you solved it? @capitanbuzz

Answer (score 1):

What OS and Docker version are you using?  There are known issues with volume mounting on older versions of Docker - OpenShift/Kube mounts volumes into containers, but when Docker is running OpenShift the stock Docker version hides access to the root mounts.  Red Hat OS's carry a patch that makes this works, supposedly Docker 1.10 will carry the right fix.  The alternate is to download the binary directly and simply start it with `sudo openshift start`.

Comment: Updated with the info, any ideas? Can you point me to the bugs that you mention are to be solved in 1.10?